# Call a VF Page from the method

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
webService static String getEmployeeDetails(String EmployeeId) { 
    List<Employee__c> emp = new List<Employee__c>(); 
    for (Employee__c empc : [Select Id, Name, EmpID from Employee__c where EmpID= :EmployeeId]){ 
        emp.add(empc);
    }
 return JSON.serialize(emp);
}
```

I want to call a VF page which uses the id parameter of Employee object  i.e for a particular Employee record a VF page will be called using the Employyee id ?

Comment: Please add more details. Are you using custom JS button on a standard layout (webservice method)?

Comment: @DenisPereverzev - Yes this is on custom JS

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`PageReference Class`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) for that:

To call a page with some parameter:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/YourPageName?id=' + someIdVariable);
return pageRef;
```

Comment: I need to call the method to launch VF Page like this -sforce.interaction.runApex('Controller','MethodName','Employeeid=' + id, runApexAccountCallback);